# CSV Load data not importing file

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, load

Importing CSV into MySQL by PHPmyAdmin using "CSV LOAD DATA".
The process does not throw any errors during the upload.
(I have made sure my columns are correct)
But as it returns the results, there are none.

Over 51000 rows of data in the spreadsheet, and "Browse" returns zero results.
Any suggestions? Maybe I am uploading too large of a spreadsheet?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you will get better answers if you post some sample code of your browse routine.

Answer (score 0):

All the fields need to be enclosed in quotes. Your best bet is to use an Excel file with a macro that does that for you. I wrote a tutorial on how to do just what you're describing which includes a link to an Excel file with a macro. [Here's a link](http://inorganik.net/blog/?p=1103).